# How to increase model class field at some rate in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am creating a product page(10 products) in Django, wherein I need to increase dummy views in all products by some rate.

Dummy Views(D) on any product during a given day N is **`D = N * Y * X`** where X for each product is selected randomly already for each product(also will be constant thereafter) and Y is taken randomly from a set each day for different products.

So basically I need to increase views on each refresh of page and as a result **`D/24*60`**, would give us an increase in views per minute.

How exactly I can increase my views at some rate per minute?

Models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField()
    views = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'productImages/')
    dateUploaded =  models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Daytimestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    actualViews = models.IntegerField(null = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

class Views(models.Model):
    X = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank = True))
    Y = ArrayField(models.FloatField(blank= True))
    Viewtimestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My home function in views.py is

```
def home(request):
    products = Products.objects.all()
    views = Views.objects.all()

    # caculate Days(N)
    delta = (datetime.date.today()-products[0].dateUploaded)
    if delta.days == 0:
        Day = 1
    else:
        Day = delta.days + 1

    # if next day then change Y
    if datetime.date.today() != products[0].Daytimestamp:
        makeY() #this function changes Y array
        for product in products:
            product.Daytimestamp = datetime.date.today()
            product.save()

    # give minutes passed since last update
    delta = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc) - views[0].Viewtimestamp
    print("Seconds passed", delta.seconds)
    v0 = views[0]
    v0.Viewtimestamp = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    v0.save()
    minutes_passed = (delta.seconds)/60

    for product in products:
        DummyView = Day * views[0].X[product.id-1] * views[0].Y[product.id-1]
        DummyViewPerMinute = (DummyView/(24*60))

        product.views += (minutes_passed * DummyViewPerMinute)
        product.save()

    return render(request, '../templates/home.html', {'Products': products})
```

I am keeping a track of the timestamp of last time the views were updated(Viewtimestamp) and increasing the views by minutes passed but views doesn't seems to increase.